# Which Layouts support animateLayoutChanges

Tags: android, android-layout

I often used `animateLayoutChanges` in the xml to fade-in/-out a View when I change its `Visibility` later in code.

When I search for examples of it it is mostly used in combination with a `LinearLayout`. But it also works with `RelativeLayout`.

**Question:**

What Layouts support `animateLayoutChanges` (to fadein/out) and is there an offical documentation? It would also be helpful if someone could tell me if any parent class like `ViewGroup` handles it and all of the SubClasses support `animateLayoutChanges`

**Addition:**

The [tutorial page](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/animation/layout.html#add) says:

> In your activity's layout XML file, set the
>   android:animateLayoutChanges attribute to true for the layout that you
>   want to enable animations for.

So my first guess would be, it works for all layouts? But does it also for Views like `ScrollView`, `TableRow` etc. which are also  indirect SubClasses of `ViewGroup`.

Has anyone experience with this?

Comment: it works for any class extending `ViewGroup`

Comment: How do you know that? Would be great if you could post a detailed answer.

Comment: just read `ViewGroup` javadocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`animateLayoutChanged` was introduced in API 11 for every `ViewGroup`, there is also related method `setLayoutTransition` (and other). more in doc of ViewGroup [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#setLayoutTransition%28android.animation.LayoutTransition%29) and on top of doc there is section with extending classes (`Known Direct Subclasses`)

Comment: of course, but note that every subclass might have `Override`n `LayoutTransition` methods